# Udf with multiple argument failes when called in dataframel

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am working in Scala and spark sql where I want to call UDF which takes multiple arguments. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my call

the udf is

```
private def parseJsonUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(parseJson _)
def parseJson (json: org.json.JSONObject, arg1: String, arg2: String = ""): String = {
  ***
}
```

I am calling it this way, here fields is Seq[String] and data column contains json string

```
for(field <- fields){
 df.withColumn(field, parseJsonUdf(col("data"), lit(field)))
}
```

Probably I dont know how to pass the string as JSONOBJECT inside udf or something else. I get the below runtime error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ********$$parseJsonUdf$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function2

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.<init>(ScalaUDF.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction.apply(UserDefinedFunction.scala:71)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try to put the 3rd argument as `lit("")`

Comment: Need more info on how is you "data" column looks like and what is the type of "data" column.

Comment: @SathiyanS: type of data column is string and the data inside is a json string.

Comment: @SomeshwarKale: when I add third arg -lit(""), I get this error java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Simply pass it as string and convert it into `JSONObject` inside UDF and do watever you want.

Comment: as @SomeshwarKale mentioned

Answer (score 0):

try below (naive approach)-

```scala
private def parseJsonUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(parseJson _)
def parseJson (jsonString: String, arg1: String, arg2: String = ""): String = {
val jsonObj:org.json.JSONObject = // parse  jsonString -> JSONObject
***
}
```

then call-

```scala
for(field <- fields){
 df.withColumn(field, parseJsonUdf(col("data"), lit(field), lit("")))
}
```